# couchbase java Authentication Failure issue

Tags: java, connection, couchbase

I have created json document 'test' inside couchbase bucket 'SAMPLE' which is remote .
URL for couchbase is *http://testcouch.employee.com:8091/index.html*
-- IP is 124.10.0.2

UserName for couch: helloUser

Password for couch: helloUser++

```
Connection.java

static CouchbaseEnvironment couchbaseEnvironment = DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment.builder()
        .queryTimeout(10000)
        .build();

    static Cluster cluster = CouchbaseCluster.create(couchbaseEnvironment,"http://testcouch.employee.com");

    static Bucket bucket = cluster.openBucket("SAMPLE","helloUser++");
```

When trying to connect getting below error:

> WARNING: [null][KeyValueEndpoint]: Could not connect to endpoint, retrying with delay 32 MILLISECONDS: 
>   com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.kv.AuthenticationException: Authentication Failure
>       at com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.kv.KeyValueAuthHandler.checkIsAuthed(KeyValueAuthHandler.java:288)
>       at com.couchbase.client.core.endpoint.kv.KeyValueAuthHandler.channelRead0(KeyValueAuthHandler.java:173)

Answer (score 3):

I got the same error. When creating a bucket from the UI there is no option to define a "password" at bucket level (v community 5.0.0).

Instead I created a user and give him admin right on target bucket. In the menu pick Security and then on top righ "Add user"

Specified the password on the cluster object not in `openBucket`

```
Cluster cluster = CouchbaseCluster.create(couchbaseEnvironment,"http://testcouch.employee.com");
couchBaseCluster.authenticate("helloUser", "helloUser++");
Bucket bucket = cluster.openBucket("SAMPLE","");
```

Answer (score 1):

The password given to the `cluster.openBucket` call is the one you specified when you created the bucket.

It appears you're using the Couchbase Web Console password.

If you don't recall creating a bucket password, try eliminating the password from the call.